# Tox error for long_description in setup file

Tags: python, setuptools, restructuredtext, tox

Although my `README.rst` and `CHANGELOG.rst` are valid, when I use them in my setup.py, if I run the `tox check` , it returns an error like below:

> ERROR: InvocationError for command /Users/.../.tox/check/bin/python setup.py check --strict --metadata --restructuredtext (exited with code 1)

If I put some simple texts in my .rst files, there will be no error. I check my .rst files with many online validators and they are fine (rendered successfully). I also tried converting them to unix style but still, I see the same error.

Can someone help, please?#

**UPDATE:**
After trying everything with no sucess, finally, I solved the issue with manually escaping '-' charachters with '\'. This means I replaced some '-' with '\-'.

A - character inside a `` ( note that I don't mean single quote like ', I mean the small quote like this: ` ) does not need to be replaced.

Comment: Can you please post your entire configuration file and also a full output with the -vv of the tox run? Without that we will not be able to understand what happening and help you!

Answer (score 1):

my guess, if missed, you may need to specify explicitly the content-type like so

```
long_description_content_type = text/x-rst
```

refer to this topic https://packaging.python.org/guides/making-a-pypi-friendly-readme/#including-your-readme-in-your-package-s-metadata

Comment: Thank you for your response, I used the 'long_description_content_type' but it didn't solve the issue. I have updated my question with the solution that I found.